# Appium: failed to locate open application error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-desktop

I am using C#, Appium, and WinAppDriver to automate UI tests on a desktop application, however, I continue to have an intermittent issue when launching the WPF application. I have done a lot of research on this but cannot find a solid solution.

When opening the application there is a login splash screen. When the correct login credentials are entered there is another loading splash screen for approximately 5 seconds before the application opens.

I continue to get the following exception when opening the application; it appears to be random. Every time I think I found a pattern I find another data point that conflict with the pattern I thought I identified.

**Exception**

```
 Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to locate opened application window with appId: C:\Program Files (x86)\path to .exe\, and processId: 14124

Stack Trace: 
RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
AppiumDriver`1.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
RemoteWebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
AppiumDriver`1.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities appiumOptions)
WindowsDriver`1.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, AppiumOptions AppiumOptions)
```

**Login code**

```
            if (session == null){
                 AppiumOptions appOptions = new AppiumOptions();
                 appOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", Path);
                 appOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Windows");
                 appOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
                 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            
                 session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appOptions);
                 Assert.IsNotNull(session);
                 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                 var allWindowHandles = session.WindowHandles;
                 session.SwitchTo().Window(allWindowHandles[0]);
                 session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

                 //Enter password and login
                 session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("tbPwd").SendKeys("password");
                 session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("btnLogin").Click();
         
                 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                 session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appOptions);
                 session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            }
```

**Tear down code after each test case**

```
public void TearDown()
            {
            AppiumOptions appOptions = new AppiumOptions();
            appOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "Root");
            session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appOptions);

            // Use the session to control the desktop
            session.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Command + "r");
            session.Keyboard.SendKeys(Keys.Null);
            session.Keyboard.SendKeys(@"C:\path of taskkill file.bat"+ Keys.Enter);

            //End current session instance
            session.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: The teardown code looks odd to me... seems like you should just quit the session... (session.quit()?)  Instead you're creating a new one and running a batch file?  Having said that, I've never used WindowsDriver before, so maybe that's necessary?  Still seems like you're creating orphaned drivers.   If it's anything like the webdrivers, the quit() method should close and dispose of the driver.

Comment: I originally tried just using the session.quit() to close the application and session, but that did not close the application so that's when I decided to use the batch file. I am initializing a new session with the app capability to Root rather path because at that point I want to control the desktop. I have also used the same code but used session.Quit() rather than session.Dispose();. From my understanding, for my purposes they are doing the same thing - clearing the session object from memory.

Comment: Interesting that you can do that... web browser drivers are pretty much limited to the DOM.   You are over-writing your session reference there before quitting the driver which means you'll have two WindowsDrivers running (I think...).   I would also avoid "session.Dispose()"... that may not shutdown things correctly.  Use .quit() which will probably call dispose when done.... then dispose() if necessary.  If WindowsDriver is like the WebDriver, quit() will close the program it's controlling, cleanup, close the driver, and then dispose... (reference will be null afterwards)

Comment: It may take some time for the application to close... be sure to wait a bit before starting a new driver.  (the application may perform it's own cleanup procedures on shutdown, such as saving config files, or things to do with the windows driver session itself... the driver probably doesn't know when the application has closed....it just sends a command "close" and then does it's own closing...)  You should only need taskkill in cases where the driver has crashed.  (to close the app it was controlling)

Comment: I was heading in the same thought process you're in. I did use the .quit(), which I will switch back to, but when I was using it I got the same results. I will use the .quit() in combination with the taskkill becasue .quit() does not close the application. I just added a delay after closing the session. However, I saw this issue now when opening the application for the first time. The WinAppDriver was closed and reopened right before starting the test.